# A function that takes one of two child classes and calls the same function on them

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, object

I have two classes that both extend a parent class. I want to write a function that can take either class but calls the childs function.

i.e.:

```
class employee
{
public:
    employee();
    virtual ~employee();
    int wage;
    int hours;
    virtual int calculatePay() =0;

};

class factoryWorker : public employee
{
    public:
        factoryWorker();
        int calculatePay();
};

class manager : public employee
{
    public:
        manager();
        int calculatePay();
};
```

in the main.cpp file I have a function

```
int getPay(employee anyTypeOfWorker) {
    return anyTypeOfWorker.calculatePay();
}
```

But this function always calls the parent (employee) calculatePay() function not the overriden functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Your main.cpp can't compile because `employee` is abstract.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be passing `employee` instances by value; you'll get [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) that way.

Comment: I cannot imagine what you are saying, as the calculatePay() is a pure virtual method in 'employee'. Even if it had a default implementation you would have to use the full qualified method name to call it in a child class ( employee::calculatePlay() )

Comment: @Fred Larson: there is no reason to assume that his program cannot be compiled and linked just because of his getPay signature (beside the fact that in that signature the 'employee' should be passed by pointer or at least by reference).

Comment: @boto: It can't be passed by value because a value cannot be created for an abstract class. I'd be willing to bet (if I were a betting man, which I'm not) that the OP's actual code doesn't have the pure virtual function, so slicing is what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

pass by address.

```
int getPay(employee* anyTypeOfWorker) {
    return anyTypeOfWorker->calculatePay();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if the parameter is a reference or a pointer to the base class.

```
int getPay(employee& anyTypeOfWorker) {
    return anyTypeOfWorker.calculatePay();
}
```

If you pass by value, the parameter will be "sliced" to the declared parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't actually call `employee::calculatePay()` since it's pure virtual, but the reason your code is *trying* to is that the object gets "sliced" down to an `employee` in the process of copying it into `getPay()`'s stack frame.

You need to pass a pointer or reference so that `getPay()` can access the caller's actual `factoryworker` or `manager` object.  For example:

```
int getPay(employee const &anyTypeOfWorker) {
    return anyTypeOfWorker.calculatePay();
}
```

Comment: You can't call a non-const member function if you pass the parameter by const reference.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I overlooked that.  `calculatePay()` should be declared const anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a pointer to "anyTypeOfWorker", so it would be

```
int getPay(employee* anyTypeOfWorker) {
    return anyTypeOfWorker->calculatePay();
}
```

For references as to why, please take a look at the following

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13885/